# Cannot append comparison value to DOM using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

The following function checks a form submission value against a data set. Currently, I am able to return a match using console.log. My question is, given that the function is working correctly in terms of comparison, how can I append the result to the body of my page? I attempted it with the following but could not get it to work:

```
function lookForMatches(){
  const slugName = `${slugData.slug()}`;
  for (var i = 0; i < globalArticles.length; i++) {
    if(slugName === globalArticles[i]["slug"]){
      const showMatches = document.createElement('div')
      showMatches.innerHTML(`<p>${globalArticles[i]["slug"]}<p>`);
      document.getElementById("slugResults").appendChild(showMatches);
    }
    else {
      console.log("No Matches")
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a function, it's a property you assign to: `showMatches.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: Didn't you get an error like `showMatches.innerHTML is not a function`?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, [`innerHTML` is a property, not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> The [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) property `innerHTML` gets or sets the HTML or XML markup contained within the element.
>
> ```
> const content = element.innerHTML;
>
> element.innerHTML = htmlString;
> ```

In your case, your code should look like this:

```js
function lookForMatches() {
  const slugName = `${slugData.slug()}`;
  for (var i = 0; i < globalArticles.length; i++) {
    if (slugName === globalArticles[i]["slug"]) {
      const showMatches = document.createElement("div");

      // Set's the inner HTML
      showMatches.innerHTML = `<p>${globalArticles[i]["slug"]}</p>`;

      document.getElementById("slugResults").appendChild(showMatches);
    } else {
      console.log("No Matches");
    }
  }
}
```